# Calculating Standard Deviation of Lognormal Returns with Partial Information

Tags: standard-deviation

I’m using a stock market portfolio simulation program that unfortunately only provides annualized standard deviation and CAGR (compounded annual growth rate) for the simulated strategy. I would like to do Welch’s test, the two-sample t-test, to determine if the simulated portfolio returns are statistically different from the benchmark’s returns. The key inputs I need for this test are the average and standard deviation. Since log returns LN(1+r) are supposed to be closer to a normal distribution than simple returns (r), I would like to perform the 2-sample t-test on the log returns. However, all the program provides is the annualized standard deviation of the simple returns (r) and the CAGR.

So to summarize, I know CAGR and annualized standard deviation of simple returns (r). Is there a way to use this info to calculate the arithmetic average and standard deviation of the corresponding log returns, i.e. LN(1+r) given what I know?

Note: I believe I can probably calculate the average of the LN(1+r) return stream with this formula: LN(1+(1+CAGR)^(1/251)-1). I used 251 in the exponent because there are 251 trading days in a year. So, I probably can get the mean of the log returns.

So, all I'm really trying to figure out is how to get the standard deviation of the log returns (LN(1+r)) given what I know.

Thanks!

Comment: Despite what some terminology would seem to suggest, it is impossible for any finite set of numbers to have either a normal or a lognormal distribution. Your problem seems to stem from confounding the properties of a *distribution* with properties of finite *samples* from that distribution. Therefore, by researching the distinction between distributions and samples you might be able to resolve this issue to your satisfaction.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for the reply. I understand what you're saying, I see my mistake. That said, is it possible to somehow calculate the sample standard deviation of Y given the sample mean of Y and the sample variance of X if all the members of Y are equal to LN(X)... as in the example above? I'm not making any statements about the nature of the distribution of samples X and Y, except for the fact that all Y is Y=LN(X). - Thanks!

Comment: If that is what you want to know, then I would suggest editing this question (radically) so it clearly reflects that. You might be able to stave off additional requests for clarification by also explaining how you could possibly know the mean of the logarithms and the SD of the raw data but somehow *not* know the other two moments--the SD of the logarithms and the mean of the raw data.

Comment: @whuber, Thank for the feedback, I edited the question as you suggested.